# Swift protocols and equatable

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I'm still learning how to work with arrays of objects implementing protocols with associated types.

I have the following protocols:

```
public protocol Word : Equatable, Hashable { // compiles

    associatedtype WordType : Equatable

    var moreWords: [WordType] { get }

}

public protocol WordDataSource { // compiles

    associatedtype SomeWord : Word

    func findWord(spelling: String) -> SomeWord?

}
```

I have `WordA`, `WordB` and `WordC` all implementing `Word` and subclassing `NSObject`

Basically, I want to implement the datasource protocol using different kinds of class implementing the Word class. This is the kind of code I would like to write, but obviously it doesn't compile.

```
class MyDataSource : WordDataSource {

    func findWord(spelling: String) -> SomeWord? {

         if conditionA {
             return WordA()
         }
         if conditionB {
             return WordB()
         } 
         if conditionA {
             return WordC()
         } 
    }

}
```

Is that even possible in Swift? What should I write to make that work?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, and it's not possible for a reason. Let's assume that your class `MyDataSource` does compile. Now, we could write such code:

```
let fooWord = MyDataSource().findWord(spelling: "Foo") // Would return WordA instance
let barWord = MyDataSource().findWord(spelling: "Bar") // Would return WordB instance
```

but all we know about those two types is that they are of this `SomeWord` type. So they should be comparable, since `Word` is comparable, right?

But they're two completely different types, so how would you know how should they be compared? Take a look at the definition of `Equatable` protocol:

`public static func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool`

You can only compare two objects of the same type that conform to this protocol.